# Unfortunately stopped, maybe due to mistakes in app

Tags: java, android, xml

I got after writing my code and running the debugger:

> "Unfortunately App has stopped"

It was working before I make some changes.. then it does not work 
and I don't know why!

my program is a GPA calculator

MainActivity.java

```
package com.mainuser.gpa.gpa;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Button mcalculate;
    TextView mshowResultTV;
    private EditText meditText1;
    private EditText meditText2;
    private EditText meditText3;
    private EditText meditText4;
    private EditText meditText5;
    private EditText meditText6;
    private EditText meditText7;
    private EditText meditText8;
    private EditText meditText9;
    private EditText meditText10;
    private EditText meditText11;
    private EditText meditText12;
    double  gradnum1,gradnum2, gradnum3, gradnum4, gradnum5,
            gradnum6, hournum1,hournum2,hournum3,hournum4,hournum5, hournum6 , pointsum=0, hoursum=0;
    double x, y, z;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initControls();
    }

    private void initControls() {

        meditText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        meditText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        meditText3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        meditText4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        meditText5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        meditText6 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        meditText7 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        meditText8 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText8);
        meditText9 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText9);
        meditText10 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText10);
        meditText11 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText11);
        meditText12 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText12);
        mshowResultTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showResultTV);
        mcalculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);

        mcalculate.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick (View v)
            {  GPAcalculate(); }});

    }


        private void GPAcalculate()
    {
        x = CalculatePoints();
        y = CalculateHours();
        z = x/y;
        mshowResultTV.setText(Double.toString(z));
    }

    private double CalculatePoints() { // multiplying each grade by hour the add to pointsum

        gradnum1 = Double.parseDouble(meditText1.getText().toString());

        if (isEmpty(meditText3)== true){ // if  the edittext empty set it to zero
            meditText3.setText("0");
            gradnum2 = Double.parseDouble(meditText3.getText().toString());
        }
        else  gradnum2 = Double.parseDouble(meditText3.getText().toString());


        if (isEmpty(meditText5)== true){
            meditText5.setText("0");
            gradnum3 = Double.parseDouble(meditText5.getText().toString());
        }
        else  gradnum3 = Double.parseDouble(meditText5.getText().toString());


        if (isEmpty(meditText7)== true){
            meditText7.setText("0");
            gradnum4 = Double.parseDouble(meditText7.getText().toString());
        }
        else  gradnum4 = Double.parseDouble(meditText7.getText().toString());


        if (isEmpty(meditText9)== true){
            meditText9.setText("0");
            gradnum5 = Double.parseDouble(meditText9.getText().toString());
        }
        else  gradnum5 = Double.parseDouble(meditText9.getText().toString());


        if (isEmpty(meditText11)== true){
            meditText11.setText("0");
            gradnum6 = Double.parseDouble(meditText11.getText().toString());
        }
        else  gradnum6 = Double.parseDouble(meditText11.getText().toString());

        hournum1 = Double.parseDouble(meditText2.getText().toString());
        hournum2 = Double.parseDouble(meditText4.getText().toString());
        hournum3  = Double.parseDouble(meditText6.getText().toString());
        hournum4  = Double.parseDouble(meditText8.getText().toString());
        hournum5  = Double.parseDouble(meditText10.getText().toString());

        if (isEmpty(meditText12)== true){
            meditText12.setText("0");
            hournum6  = Double.parseDouble(meditText12.getText().toString());
        }
        else   hournum6  = Double.parseDouble(meditText12.getText().toString());


        pointsum = (gradnum1*hournum1) + (gradnum2*hournum2) + (gradnum3*hournum3) + (gradnum4*hournum4) + (gradnum5*hournum5) + (gradnum6*hournum6);

        return pointsum;
    }


    private double CalculateHours() { // adding numb of hours

        hournum1 = Double.parseDouble(meditText2.getText().toString());
        hournum2 = Double.parseDouble(meditText4.getText().toString());
        hournum3  = Double.parseDouble(meditText6.getText().toString());
        hournum4  = Double.parseDouble(meditText8.getText().toString());
        hournum5  = Double.parseDouble(meditText10.getText().toString());


        if (isEmpty(meditText12)== true){
            meditText12.setText("0");
            hournum6  = Double.parseDouble(meditText12.getText().toString());
        }
        else   hournum6  = Double.parseDouble(meditText12.getText().toString());

        hoursum = hournum1 + hournum2 + hournum3 + hournum4 + hournum5 + hournum6;
        return hoursum;
    }

    private boolean isEmpty ( EditText x ) { // fuction to check if a certain edit text is empty or not
        return
                x.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0; }



}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mainuser.gpa.gpa" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon3"
        android:label="GPA Calculater"
        android:theme = "@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Calculater"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

    <TextView
        android:text="Please insert the following .. "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:id="@+id/viewhello"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewhello"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/Sub1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Subject 1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Sub1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/Sub2"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Subject 2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Sub2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/Sub3"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Subject 3"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Sub3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/Sub4"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Subject 4"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Sub4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/Sub5"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Subject 5"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"/>
    <Button
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Sub5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/Sub6"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:text="Subject 6"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/calculate"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Calculate"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText11"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText11"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText11"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Sub1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"

        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"

        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"/>

       <EditText
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"

        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"

        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"

        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"/>


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"

        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText8"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText10"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText9"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText9"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText11"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText9"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"

        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText12"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText11"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText11"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"

        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"

        />
    <Button
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/GPA"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:text="SEM GPA"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:layout_below="@+id/calculate"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText11"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText11"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/Hours"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Hours"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editText1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/Grade"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:text="Grade"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Hours"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Hours"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Hours" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/showResultTV"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/GPA"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText12"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText12"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

logcat

```
07-02 07:27:09.970    1193-1193/com.mainuser.gpa.gpa W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.mainuser.gpa.gpa is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
07-02 07:27:10.020    1193-1193/com.mainuser.gpa.gpa I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
07-02 07:27:14.140    1193-1199/com.mainuser.gpa.gpa I/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger is active
07-02 07:27:14.340    1193-1193/com.mainuser.gpa.gpa I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
07-02 07:27:14.340    1193-1193/com.mainuser.gpa.gpa I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-02 07:27:14.560    1193-1193/com.mainuser.gpa.gpa I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-02 07:27:14.780    1193-1193/com.mainuser.gpa.gpa I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-02 07:27:14.980    1193-1193/com.mainuser.gpa.gpa I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-02 07:27:15.180    1193-1193/com.mainuser.gpa.gpa I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-02 07:27:15.800    1193-1193/com.mainuser.gpa.gpa I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-02 07:27:16.000    1193-1193/com.mainuser.gpa.gpa I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-02 07:27:16.220    1193-1193/com.mainuser.gpa.gpa I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
07-02 07:27:17.840    1193-1193/com.mainuser.gpa.gpa I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1632)
07-02 07:27:20.890    1193-1193/com.mainuser.gpa.gpa D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-02 07:27:20.890    1193-1193/com.mainuser.gpa.gpa W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1ae8ba8)
07-02 07:27:21.980    1193-1193/com.mainuser.gpa.gpa E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mainuser.gpa.gpa, PID: 1193
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mainuser.gpa.gpa/com.mainuser.gpa.gpa.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:151)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
            at com.mainuser.gpa.gpa.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

error logcat

```
07-02 07:27:21.980    1193-1193/com.mainuser.gpa.gpa E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mainuser.gpa.gpa, PID: 1193
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mainuser.gpa.gpa/com.mainuser.gpa.gpa.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:151)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
            at com.mainuser.gpa.gpa.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the logs from logcat to debug the problem

Comment: post your logcat here to debug your problem

Comment: in logcat What message showing ??

Comment: I add it , could you please check it

Answer (score 0):

First of all please naming your methods as Java Naming Convention requiring (starting with lowercase, 'cause uppercase is for Classes).

Then your checking condition on EditText is Empty or not, should be like that:

```
if (meditText1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
}
```

Comment: which method do you mean ? could you please give me an example .. actually it was working before I don't  know where the mistake

Answer (score 0):

Its because you use the new google's approach, with AppCompat theme, just go to Manifest, find  mark and put a valid theme - @android:style/Theme.AppCompat.

Comment: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'them' with value '@android:style/AppThem')

Comment: That appear when I am trying to changing it to @android:style/Theme.AppTheme